# Style rules based on wrapping parent classes

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm pulling some components from my react app into a component library, and updating them to be styled-components so I can use them in another project ssr. First step: get these components working in a library as styled-components for the current project

I have a component which currently has additional scss rules when it is used within certain parents. e.g.

```
.myElement {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.specialCase {
  .myElement {
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
}
```

How do I adapt this into a styled component? If I have my styled component like:

```
styled(MyElement)`
  border: 1px solid red;
`
```

Obviously I cant use the `.specialCase` parent selector in here.

I have a couple of restrictions - the component higher up that provides the `.specialCase` class is not a styled component, and is not in the component library. Also I do not want to have conditional rules in the component, as I want this style change to happen without a react rerender. i.e. when the class is added to it's parent, it shouldn't have to rerender myElement.

Can anyone help me with an approach that might solve this? I am new to styled-components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent component can still select `.myElement`, you just need to add a `className="myElement"` to the styled component.

In the next example, `Container` can be any component (don't have to be `styled`):

```
const Container = styled.div`
  .myElement {
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }
`;

const Child = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid red;
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Child className="myElement">Hello</Child>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit quiet-frost-do2hs]

Comment: Of course - so simple. I was far overthinking it. Thank you